# Netty websocket message compression

Tags: websocket, compression, netty

My Netty version is 4.1.5.Final and it supports websocket message compression.
But when send one message to many clients (clientA, clientB, clientC), the same message will be compressed many times according to amount of clients.
I expect that the message compressed once,but used many times.
Here is my way to solve it:

1, I compressed the message and put it into a map before call send 'message' event.

2, Normally websocket message compression operation implement in DeflateEncoder, but now when call the encode method in DeflateEncoder, first I try to get from the map, if exists, use it directly.

But I am not sure it is a good solution, any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach sounds generally fine to me.